# My tor browser can't connect

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

```
5/21/2016 23:33:12 PM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/21/2016 23:33:12 PM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/21/2016 23:33:12 PM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/21/2016 23:33:12 PM.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/21/2016 23:33:12 PM.300 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "C:\Program Files (x86)\New folder\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.1" 
5/21/2016 23:33:12 PM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
5/21/2016 23:33:34 PM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
5/21/2016 23:33:34 PM.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
5/21/2016 23:33:34 PM.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
5/21/2016 23:33:34 PM.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
5/21/2016 23:33:38 PM.700 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
5/21/2016 23:33:39 PM.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 40%: Loading authority key certs 
5/21/2016 23:33:40 PM.100 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
5/22/2016 0:53:27 AM.500 [NOTICE] Your system clock just jumped 2617 seconds forward; assuming established circuits no longer work. 
5/22/2016 0:53:27 AM.500 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 40%: Loading authority key certs. (No route to host [WSAEHOSTUNREACH ]; NOROUTE; count 2; recommendation warn; host 43868B33C3A3772C74CF9545CC2CC6E62D770D27 at 130.184.75.118:9001) 
5/22/2016 0:53:27 AM.500 [WARN] 1 connections have failed: 
5/22/2016 0:53:27 AM.500 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
5/22/2016 2:09:56 AM.200 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 40%: Loading authority key certs. (No route to host [WSAEHOSTUNREACH ]; NOROUTE; count 3; recommendation warn; host 9504CB22EEB25D344DE63CB7A6F2C46F895C3686 at 46.101.102.71:443) 
5/22/2016 2:09:56 AM.200 [WARN] 1 connections have failed: 
5/22/2016 2:09:56 AM.200 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
5/22/2016 2:09:56 AM.200 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 40%: Loading authority key certs. (No route to host [WSAEHOSTUNREACH ]; NOROUTE; count 4; recommendation warn; host BEEF6A5841D293F98DB79BFD80F8C1A480A1A886 at 212.83.138.123:443) 
5/22/2016 2:09:56 AM.200 [WARN] 1 connections have failed: 
5/22/2016 2:09:56 AM.200 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
5/22/2016 2:09:56 AM.200 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/22/2016 2:09:56 AM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/22/2016 2:09:56 AM.200 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/22/2016 2:09:56 AM.200 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
5/22/2016 2:09:56 AM.200 [NOTICE] Your system clock just jumped 1282 seconds forward; assuming established circuits no longer work. 
5/22/2016 2:09:57 AM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/22/2016 2:09:57 AM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/22/2016 2:09:57 AM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/22/2016 2:09:57 AM.400 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/22/2016 2:10:00 AM.000 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
5/22/2016 2:10:44 AM.100 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/22/2016 2:10:44 AM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/22/2016 2:10:44 AM.100 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/22/2016 2:10:44 AM.700 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
5/22/2016 3:44:04 AM.500 [NOTICE] Your system clock just jumped 1621 seconds forward; assuming established circuits no longer work. 
5/22/2016 3:45:01 AM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/22/2016 3:45:01 AM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/22/2016 3:45:01 AM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/22/2016 3:45:01 AM.800 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/22/2016 3:45:04 AM.000 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
5/22/2016 3:46:36 AM.300 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/22/2016 3:46:36 AM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/22/2016 3:46:36 AM.300 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/22/2016 3:46:36 AM.500 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
5/22/2016 3:51:02 AM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/22/2016 3:51:02 AM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/22/2016 3:51:02 AM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/22/2016 3:51:02 AM.500 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/22/2016 3:51:10 AM.400 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'ndnop0' (fresh): $1E05F577A0EC0213F971D81BF4D86A9E4E8229ED~ndnop0 at 109.105.109.163 
5/22/2016 3:51:10 AM.400 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
5/22/2016 3:51:10 AM.400 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'ndnop2' (fresh): $4C331FA9B3D1D6D8FB0D8FBBF0C259C360D97E6A~ndnop2 at 109.105.109.163 
5/22/2016 3:51:10 AM.400 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
5/22/2016 3:51:13 AM.300 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'Unnamed' (fresh): $AF9F66B7B04F8FF6F32D455F05135250A16543C9~Unnamed at 169.229.59.74 
5/22/2016 3:51:13 AM.300 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
5/22/2016 3:51:13 AM.700 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'LeifEricson' (fresh): $A09D536DD1752D542E1FBB3C9CE4449D51298239~LeifEricson at 83.212.101.3 
5/22/2016 3:51:13 AM.700 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
5/22/2016 3:52:00 AM.500 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/22/2016 3:52:00 AM.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/22/2016 3:52:00 AM.500 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/22/2016 3:52:00 AM.500 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
5/22/2016 3:52:37 AM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/22/2016 3:52:37 AM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/22/2016 3:52:37 AM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/22/2016 3:52:37 AM.000 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/22/2016 3:57:20 AM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 40%: Loading authority key certs. (DONE; DONE; count 7; recommendation warn; host 46D4A71197B8FA515A826C6B017C522FE264655B at 0.0.2.0:1) 
5/22/2016 3:57:20 AM.600 [WARN] 4 connections have failed: 
5/22/2016 3:57:20 AM.600 [WARN]  3 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
5/22/2016 3:57:20 AM.600 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
5/22/2016 5:33:46 AM.800 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/22/2016 5:33:46 AM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/22/2016 5:33:46 AM.800 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/22/2016 5:33:46 AM.800 [NOTICE] Your system clock just jumped 4093 seconds forward; assuming established circuits no longer work. 
5/22/2016 5:33:46 AM.800 [NOTICE] Heartbeat: Tor's uptime is 3:20 hours, with 0 circuits open. I've sent 88 kB and received 1.87 MB. 
5/22/2016 5:33:46 AM.800 [NOTICE] Average packaged cell fullness: 35.415%. TLS write overhead: 9% 
5/22/2016 5:33:57 AM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/22/2016 5:33:57 AM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/22/2016 5:33:57 AM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/22/2016 5:33:57 AM.000 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/22/2016 5:34:11 AM.800 [NOTICE] Bridge 'starman' has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address (0.0.2.0:3) based on the configured Bridge address. 
5/22/2016 5:34:11 AM.800 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'starman' (fresh): $A2C13B7DFCAB1CBF3A884B6EB99A98067AB6EF44~starman at 0.0.2.0 
5/22/2016 5:34:11 AM.800 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
5/22/2016 5:34:22 AM.000 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
5/22/2016 5:34:31 AM.900 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: No running bridges 
5/22/2016 6:48:23 AM.400 [NOTICE] Your system clock just jumped 1151 seconds forward; assuming established circuits no longer work. 
5/22/2016 6:48:23 AM.400 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 40%: Loading authority key certs. (DONE; DONE; count 8; recommendation warn; host A2C13B7DFCAB1CBF3A884B6EB99A98067AB6EF44 at 0.0.2.0:3) 
5/22/2016 6:48:23 AM.400 [WARN] 5 connections have failed: 
5/22/2016 6:48:23 AM.400 [WARN]  4 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
5/22/2016 6:48:23 AM.400 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
5/22/2016 6:48:31 AM.400 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/22/2016 6:48:31 AM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
5/22/2016 6:48:31 AM.400 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

Comment: your connection is censored - it is clearly stated in your log(in NOROUTE errors), and SSL connections are monitored/MitM'ed(in "No SSL object" strings). Pre-seed your Tor instance, try not to use an entry guards and your bridges are seems to be blocked too. A Meek pluggable transport will be of use to you, I think. Feel free to ask further questions - let's solve it together!

Comment: Your system clock is constantly jumping, something is goosed with your timesync.

Comment: Hi I have a similar problem that only started today:
"[WARN] Our clock is 31 days, 0 hours, 18 minutes behind the time published in the consensus network status document" My computer clock is fine but something is preventing me connecting. I can't even get a connection using bridges. Has the new version of tor done something to the network? Full log below:
------------------------------------------------------------
16/10/2016 14:41:01.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 16/10/2016 14:41:01.600

Comment: Sincere apologies for wasting space and time. My computer clock was one month out. No idea what changed that but as soon as I fixed I could get connections again.